# How to replace duplicate cells with blanks/nulls in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

please see the attached image. I am trying to remove the duplicate cells in the first 5 columns.

The procedure split column is the only column witch unique entries, I would like this to stay the same and then row 2 and 3 of the first 5 columns to show blank or null.. is this doable?

Many thanks for any help :)

[image]

Comment: Please mark the answer if it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using left join and row_number window function.
Please check the columns for correctness before running this query.

```
SELECT   T2.[Operation cancelled within 28 days]
        ,T2.[Number of new patients seen]
        ,T2.[Number of follow up patients seen]
        ,T2.[Readmission Rate]
        ,T2.[2 Week Target]
        ,T1.[Procedure Split] 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT [Operation cancelled within 28 days]
                     ,[Procedure Split] 
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NUM) AS RN FROM Your_table) T1

 LEFT JOIN 

    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  [Operation cancelled within 28 days]
                                    ,[Number of new patients seen]
                                    ,[Number of follow up patients seen]
                                    ,[Readmission Rate]
                                    ,[2 Week Target]
                                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A) AS RN FROM Your_table) X 
    WHERE RN=1 ) T2
ON T1.RN = T2.RN
```